# How to shave pubic hair and prevent razor burn and ingrown hair?

Tags: inflammation, shaving-razor-burn

**How to shave pubic hair and prevent razor burn and ingrown hair?**

It seems that every time I try to shave my pubic hair (like a bikini line), I always make it look a lot worse than before shaving... I'd much rather have a few swaths of hair than bright red inflamed razor burn and itchy red ingrown hairs.

I always make sure my razor is sharp and clean, and that my skin isn't lather/shaving cream is non-scented (so as not to irritate my skin), and that the skin is warm from the water and well covered in lather, and then I shave. And it looks and feels good for about 24 hours, but after that.... all sorts of tiny welts bubble up and I begin itching up a storm.

**Is there a certain direction to shave? Is there a different instrument I should be using instead of my razor? 
How do I shave my pubic hair without it backfiring on me?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should trim the pubic hair preferably with scissors before shaving.

You may even consider only trimming alone. But if you must shave, then trim first. Also endeavour to stretch your skin  before shaving. And apply Aloe Vera after shaving. Some would recommend Hydrocortisone, but I'm not a fan of medications....I'm a fan of trimming :)

http://www.livestrong.com/article/176437-how-to-keep-pubic-area-from-itching-after-shaving/

http://m.wikihow.com/Shave-Your-Pubic-Hair

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately ingrowns are tough to avoid unless you trim only or have had laser hair removal. But here are a few tips:

- trim first; hair shouldn't be more than 1/4"
- use a sharp and clean razor
- use moisturizing shaving cream
- shave in the direction of hair growth

After you're done and are completely dry, apply antibiotic ointment (like Neosporin) to the areas that you have shaved. Do this daily.

Also be sure to exfoliate all shaved areas between each shave, such as with a clean cotton washcloth, etc.